# Adding file description field to already existing records

Tags: 7, entities, files

I have a site with various hundreds of a particular content type. This content type contains a field of type file. We have decided we want to display a description rather than the filename. I have enabled the description on the file data type for the content type. It works when new files are added, but if we try to update existing files with a description it doesn't work (you can fill in the field but on Save it is not added to the record). I'm guessing that the description field wasn't created in the database when these files were added prior to the description field being added. Is there anything we can do about this, other than re-uploading all the files again, which would be rather laborious?

Comment: `I have enabled the description field on the content type` - What does this mean? It makes no sense to me. There's no default description field on `file` type fields either. If you meant the "Title" or the "Alt" fields, then those should be created in the database for the "field_data_field_..." tables. Check your database.

Comment: Using the correct terminology with Drupal is always problematic. One of the default field types in Drupal 7 is file. There is a tickbox with this field type "Enable Description field" - I have ticked that for the file field on the Content Type. I believe this to be all core 7.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've mistaken it for Image fields.